# Wilson lines, boundary condisions, surface defects of TQFTs

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

I have been studying (extended) topological quantum field theories (in short TQFTs) from the mathematical point of view and I have no background of the physics point of view. Sometimes I encountered papers talking about Wilson lines, boundary conditions, surface defects and so on. I looked up these terminology but I couldn't find a good explanation how these are related to TQFTs.

Could you suggest me references (papars, websites, books, vidoes etc) that explains the relationship between these physical jargon and TQFTs from mathematical point of view?

Or could you explain it here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cross-posted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43671/2451